# styled-components doesn't style option element

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Note: the question is linked to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) and marked as `duplicated` which doesn't make any sense.

By using styled components, I'm not able to style `option` element. Please help me to understand why it doesn't effect the style. It works for other elements such as `select` (you can also see in the example).

You can find the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sunset-ewhmm?file=/src/App.tsx):

When you click select element, you'll see that `option` has default browser style.

Comment: the question was not "how to do custom styling". It doesn't work for option element in particular and I already checked open source libraries but most of them doesn't use styled-components or they don't use native option element (they use div instead).

Comment: The duplicate is not about "how to do custom styling", its about "why you can't custom style". "It doesn't work for option element in particular", yes, thats what the duplicate answer explain why though. Tell me what doesnt make any sense, indeed for custom options you usually style a custom div.